# Python list of dictionaries incrementation error

Tags: python, dictionary

Python 3.6

I have a list of dictionaries -

```
houses = ['a', 'b', 'c']
rarity_values = {'Common':0,'uncommon':0}
rarity = {}.fromkeys([i for i in houses],rarity_values) # creates dictionary of id

print(rarity)
# {'a': {'Common': 0, 'uncommon': 0}, 'b': {'Common': 0, 'uncommon': 0}, 'c': {'Common': 0, 'uncommon': 0}}
```

I'm going through a certain document and I want to count the number of times a common thing happens in each `house`. So if I see two `Commons` for `house a` and 1 uncommon for house `b` I get the result

```
# {'a': {'Common': 2, 'uncommon': 0}, 'b': {'Common': 0, 'uncommon': 1}, 'c': {'Common': 0, 'uncommon': 0}}
```

However, I'm noticing that when I increment the value for `Common` for any one `house`, it increments it for all of them.

```
print('a (before increment)',rarity['a']['Common'])
print('b (before increment)',rarity['b']['Common'])
rarity['b']['Common'] += 1
print('a (after increment)',rarity['a']['Common'])
print('b (after increment)',rarity['b']['Common'])
```

yields the output

```
a (before increment) 0
b (before increment) 0
a (after increment) 1
b (after increment) 1
```

instead of

```
a (before increment) 0
b (before increment) 0
a (after increment) 0
b (after increment) 1
```

Since I only  incremented `b` by 1.

Or to see it better

```
{'a': {'Common': 1, 'uncommon': 0}, 'b': {'Common': 1, 'uncommon': 0}, 'c': {'Common': 1, 'uncommon': 0}}
```

which should have been

```
{'a': {'Common': 0, 'uncommon': 0}, 'b': {'Common': 1, 'uncommon': 0}, 'c': {'Common': 0, 'uncommon': 0}}
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Should I be nesting this differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use dictionary comprehension.

```
for i in houses:
    rarity[i] = dict(rarity_values)
```

In your original code, you are linking the same instance of `rarity_values` to each key 'a' and 'b'

Comment: You may be making a copy, but only one copy, not one per key. All keys still share the same dict for their value.

Comment: you have a good point

Comment: When I used `dict(rarity_values)` instead of `rarity_values`, I got the same output.

Comment: I have updated the answer